# Both Blender 3.0.1 and Blender 3.4 have startup links showing in my Ubuntu 22.04 apps. I see only Blender 3.4 In .cache and .config

Tags: linux, versions

How can I get rid of Blender 3.0.1?

Is it a subset of Blender 3.4 and there is no real need to delete it?

Comment: Hello and welcome. I'm no very sure, but i think your question is more about OS setting, than Blender. You could try Ubuntu Stack

Comment: If I go to Ubuntu/linux and ask the question, I'll have Stackexchange users suggesting it is not a Ubuntu question but instead an app question.  Very frustrating.

Comment: Maybe if you use more general terms you won't be ? Have you tried https://askubuntu.com/q/40884 ?

Comment: This is definitely not a question regarding the OS, but the Blender package provided for Ubuntu. Nevertheless, the question has nothing to do with the use of Blender itself, so this is strictly off-topic.Try removing both versions, and then installing only 3.4, maybe that will recreate the necessary startup files.

Comment: quellenform, your answer is it.  I read a bunch of answers involving terminal commands but never was sure my question was answered.  I entered:

Answer (score 0):

quellenform, your answer is it. I read a bunch of answers involving terminal commands but never was sure my question was answered.

I entered: `sudo apt autoremove --purge blender` and no longer have both versions.

Apparently, 3.4 survived and is usable without reinstallation.

Comment: Great that the comment could help you. Note: with `autoremove --purge` you remove the package with its automatically installed dependencies. The personal user settings in your home directory will be preserved.

Comment: In the end, it looks suitable for Ubuntu Stack (you can't use Sudo for Blender Windows)